# How can I rm the files from remote

Tags: git

I have push the commited files to the remote server host.But the files is that I need to delete.How can I delete the files from remote server.

Comment: Remove them from your repo, commit, push. The history will always be there though so if it's sensitive data like passwords, change those passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways can do it.
ONE:
in your local directory operation.
**`git rm FILENAME`**
**`git commit -m "WRITE SOMETHING"`**
**`git push origin master`**  #or your using branch

TWO:
in your local directory type flow:
**`git remote rm FILENAME`**
**`git commite -m "WRITE SOMETHING"`**
**`git push origin master`**  #or your using branch

Comment: `git remote rm FILENAME` is not correct - in fact such a command syntax does not exist in `git`. Option ONE is correct.

Comment: `git remote rm FILENAME` is correct.git has taht option. you can search it.

Comment: [git-remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)  @twalberg you can look at this page.

Comment: Technically, it is correct that that syntax is acceptible, however `git remote rm <something>` is not removing a `FILENAME`, but an alias for a remote repository, so `git remote rm blah` is not the same thing as `git rm blah`. I perhaps should have worded the original comment a bit better...

Answer (score 1):

If you pushed stuff that you don't want to show up in your history (passwords, swearing etc.), you can also re-write the history. But this should only be an emergency measure and can make people angry at you if they already pulled from that branch. Locally you can use `git rebase -i` to modify your history, and then push it with `git push REMOTE +BRANCH` (where `REMOTE` and `BRANCH` refer to the remote and branch names, respectively). If you want to delete the remote branch, use `git push REMOTE :BRANCH`. Notice that depending on your rights on the server (as e.g. implemented by gitolite), you are not able to rewrite the history on the server.

If it is passwords that you pushed, make sure to change them nonetheless, people might already have seen them!